# Positive integer range lookup table in CUDA/C++

Tags: c++, arrays, cuda, hashtable

I am currently optimizing a piece of code for a CUDA application which has a relatively large code section which has to map from unsigned integer ranges to array indexes, i.e. range [0..~1000]:

`if n >= 0 and n < 8 then index 0`
`if n >= 8 and n < 10 then index 1`
etc.

Since space at compile time is irrelevant I thought about creating a compile-time array which maps from the ranges to the index. I thought about packing the bits of the lower and upper range into an integer (since `n` is bound by ~1000) and mapping from that value to the array index, so something like:

```
map[(unsigned int)(0 << 16 | 7 << 16)] = 0;
map[(unsigned int)(8 << 16 | 9 << 16)] = 1;
...
```

Finding the index then would require the lookup in the same way it was set.

Does this make any sense, or has someone a better idea?

Comment: This doesn't make any sense. `8 << 16 | 9 << 16` is just `9 << 16`. What does that mean?

Comment: Use a texture, that is exactly what they are for

Comment: @talonmies aren't textures within [0..1] float range?

Comment: No, you can bind integers to textures, there just is no filtering support for non-floating point types

Comment: @talonmies alright. Do you want to post an example? Then we have one and I can accept your answer after trying it.

Comment: @Sam Are the intervals that need to be mapped back to indexes completely arbitrary, or is there some pattern to them? In other words, is the mapping potentially describable as a *computable* function (possibly logarithmic in nature)?

Comment: @njuffa arbitrary. I actually wrote a piece of code to do this now. I need to post it yet. Has two loops mapping all possible numbers to the index.

Comment: https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/cuda-pro-tip-kepler-texture-objects-improve-performance-and-flexibility/ is pretty much all you need. (Change the type to int). Populate an array with the index value for each i and you are done. If there is only around 1000 values, that is 4kb of memory, which is trivial. You get automatic caching and hardware accelerated lookup. There is no way you will be able to write anything in kernel code that would be faster

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since your range is [0..1000], and `max_index` <= `max_range` (I assume, indices are sequenced), then your can fit any index into 2-byte `uint16_t`.

Thereafter, you can create "reverse index" array size of [max_range +1], where index in the array - your value, and value of array is your original index.

For your example, beginning of the array would be:

```
uint16_t rev_map[] = { 0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1, 1, .... };
```

For convert your value to index, you can just using single retrieval:

```
uint16_t index = rev_map[value];
```

Size of your rev_map will be only 2K, so I think, can fit into your CUDA cards.

Comment: Yep, that was how I finally implemented it, just a lookup table.

Comment: I can suggest option, how to (maybe) decrease table size 2x, to 1 byte per index. Common idea: keep in the table not index, but delta between index and linearly predicted value. I.e. compute output as: `index = value / k + rev_map[value]`, where `k = max_value / max_index`. But, of course, this is slowest, than original proposal (need div/shift and add). Thus I think, original proposal with 2K table is best.

Comment: @olegarch Division by constant can be replaced with multiplication, even for integer

Comment: @olegarch remember that I wrote "CUDA" in the title. It only allows a minimum size of int, nonthing below that can be practically optimized.

Comment: @Sam The Cuda architecture provides some limited computational optimizations for small int data types, e.g. within the Tensor Cores and a few SIMD instructions like `vabsdiff2`. But of course small integers can be used for saving memory space (global and shared, less often registers) and are used quite often on Cuda for this purpose.